# cp command failing in Linux

Tags: linux

I am facing a copy command problem while executing shell script in RHEL 5.

executed command is

```
cp -fp /fir1/dir2/*/bin/file1 `find . -name file1 -print`
```

error is

```
cp: Target ./6e0476aec9667638c87da1b17b6ccf46/file1 must be a directory
```

Would you please throw some ideas why it would be failing?

Thanks
Robert.

Comment: This isn't a programming question so should really be in http://superuser.com

Comment: @chrisharris: as soon as 3 more people vote to migrate it, it will be.

Comment: What should the command do? Copy multiple files to a common destination directory or concatenate multiple files into one?

Comment: @chrisharris.: fine line... I guess it really depends how you define "programming". One could argue that it is programming related, as it is about writing a set of instructions to ask a computer to perform certain operations. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot copy multiple multiple files to a file, only to a directory, i.e.

```
cp file1 file2 file2 file4
```

is not possible, you need

```
cp file1 file2 file2 dir1
```

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I got the point. I will go and change the code accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

When `cp` is called with more than two filenames as arguments, it treats the last one as a target directory, and copies all the files named in the other arguments into that target directory. So, for example,

```
cp file1 file2 dir3
```

will create `dir3/file1` and `dir3/file2`. It seems that in your case, the pattern `/fir1/dir2/*/bin/file1` matches more than one filename, so `cp` is trying to treat the result of `find` as a target directory - which it isn't - and failing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't copy many files to one location unless that location is a directory.

cp should be used thusly: `cp sourcefile destinationfile` or `cp source1 source2 destinationdir`.

Answer (score 2):

As the others said you cannot copy multiple files to one file using `cp`. On the other hand, if you want to append the content of multiple files together into one destination file you can use `cat`.

For instance:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > destinationfile
```

Answer (score 2):

it is hard to answer without knowing what you are trying to achieve.

If, for example, you want to copy all files named "file1" within a directory structure to a target place /tmp, building the same directory structure there, this command will do the trick:

```
cd /dir1/dir2
find . -name file1 | cpio -pvd /tmp
```